# getResourceAsStream(String) with full path returns null but file exists

Tags: java, inputstream, jogl

Well I'm realy at a loss here. I try some JOGL and want to get a texture on an Object. I usually do it like this:

```
Texture[] thumbs = new Texture[pics.length];

try {
    for (int i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i ++){
        InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(pics[i].getPath());
        data = TextureIO.newTextureData(stream, false, "jpg");
        thumbs[i] = TextureIO.newTexture(data);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Usually this works fine if the jpg-file is in the source-directory but this time the file lies elsewhere and I recieve an `IOException` that says the stream was `null`.

`pics[i].getPath()` returns this String: `C:\beispieluser\bjoern\eigene_bilder\eckelsheim.jpg`. This is the exact path where the file lies. Can somebody tell me where my thoughts took the wrong turn?

Comment: `IOExeption` suppose to be thrown as you said _but this time the file lies elsewhere_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getResourceAsStream()` and friends will only open "classpath resources", which are files that appear on the classpath along with your compiled classes.  To open that file, use `new File()` or (on Java 7) `Files.newInputStream()`.

Comment: Sounds good to me. I'm trying it right now.
Damn it! That worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

getResourceAsStream() finds resources that are in the classpath. I'm pretty sure it won't work for an absolute path somewhere else on your disk.

Answer (score 0):

1. You files folder is not a part of your classpath.
   You can add it, but i don't think it proper way for resources like images to be a part of classpath.
2. Use FileInputStream:

Code:

```
try{
    for (int i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i ++){
      File file = new File(pics[i].getPath());
      FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
      data = TextureIO.newTextureData(stream, false, "jpg");
      thumbs[i] = TextureIO.newTexture(data);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```